# File Scan and separate into 2 separate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file, int

This program is supposed to read a file called data.txt that contains years and the temperature...

```
1  1950  11
2  1950  22
3  1950  65
4  1950  103
5  1950  99
```

then break them into two separate arrays and print out like the following...

```
(1950, 11)
(1950, 22)
(1950, 65)
(1950, 103)
(1950, 99)
```

But I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to make the separate the two integers from each other using an array.

Thanks

Here is my current code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        int[] year = new int[];
        for(int i = 0; i < year; i++) {
            year[i] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(year);
        }

        //int[] temperature = new int[150];
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried so far? What happened?

Comment: Sorry about that, its java

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class ReadFile {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
  int[] year = new int[];
        for(int i = 0; i < year; i++) {
            year[i] = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println(year);
  }

  //int[] temperature = new int[150];
 }
}

Comment: Please modify your answer and include the code there. That way we get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have does not even compile. You need to specify how big the int array is going to be, for example:

```
int[] year = new int[1024];
```

The loop needs to compare against the length of the array, not against the array itself:

```
for(int i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
```

When you try to print the year, you're again dealing with an array, not a single number, and will end up with something like `[I@7ea987ac`. So specify the index if the array element you want to print.

```
System.out.println(year[i]);
```

Since you just want to print the numbers, I don't see why you need an array in the first place.

Not using an array also saves you the trouble of guessing correctly how large it needs to be. Just read and print until all input is done.

You also need to ignore that line number from your sample input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            input.nextInt(); // dummy line number
            int year = input.nextInt();
            int temp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("(" + year + ", " + temp + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get what your saying, I had that a while ago and tried to turn it into an array from there, but I was unsuccessful.  Unfortunately it needs to be an array.

Comment: @ChrisBrocato Why does it need to be an array?